# X-Failed-Recipients value in json output

Tags: get, message, gmail-api, google-workspace, payload

I am pulling the api [https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/{(id)}](https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%7BuserId%7D/messages/%7B(id)%7D)

I get the full body with all the headers and values in the output but I need to generate the response schema to give me the property under payload for name: X-Failed-Recipients, value:{}

I have tried everything I know and nothing works.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).